# How do I destroy an existing DataTable object without a reference?

Tags: jquery, datatables

When I create a DataTable, (`$('.tableContainer table').DataTable({ ... })`), I don't retain the object reference. Later on in the script, I want to destroy the table, but the only thing I know about it is the selector. Having not kept the original object reference, how do I find the table object to destroy it?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Actually, it is. You'll notice when you post a question, there is a button directly under it that says "answer your own question Q&A style". This is something stack overflow actually encourages, as you can see here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: I agree @BenuBird!! NOM!! It was out of my knowledge. Thanks for sharing.. :) I am removing my comment.. :)

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the table object instance, call DataTable on the table (just as you did when creating it), but pass it an object with bRetrieve=true.

```
table = $('.tableContainer table').DataTable({ 'bRetrieve':true });
```

This returns the original instance.

Next, to destroy it, you need to call fnDestroy(), *not* Destroy(). I don't know why this is, but it appears that any methods you want to call on the retrieved object need to be prefixed with "fn".

```
table.fnDestroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Following link might help solve your issue: 
https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy

table = $('.tableContainer table').DataTable({ 'destroy':true });
```

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work, for two reasons: 1. It REPLACES the table, I just want to remove it. 2) I suspect it might be internally calling Destroy, instead of fnDestroy.

Comment: try this on button click
var table = $('.tableContainer').DataTable();
 
$('#tableDestroy').on( 'click', function () {
    table.destroy();
} );

Comment: Yes, that's the default way to do it described in the docs. However, it's no use in my case, because I don't have access to the "var table" - as I say in the original question, I have NOT kept the original object reference, so I need a way to get the table by its css selector.

Comment: I think you should always keep the reference, can you send me full code of how you created the table?

Comment: No, its a big complicated program involving multiple files. One of them creates the table, and a different one needs to destroy it if present, so the only way to keep the reference would be to store it in the global scope, which is terrible practice.